# Does Titanium is the best way for Mobile Developer?

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, titanium, titanium-mobile

Hi a new programming with Mobile, Right now I had a little knowledge with android and iPhone, I wanna my progress work to be quick and have good result.

I research 2 day with Titanium and it seem good with android and iPhone, but the requirement is java script programming.

So, Do i need switch to javascript and work with Titanium?

please give some idea from your mobile experience!

Thanks;

Comment: There have been similar questions on SO, search around. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976596/titanium-mobile-development-platform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

titanium is open source too. and if you want to use community version than you don't have to pay anything to Appcelerator. And titanium will convert your code to native it will not run your code in web browsers like phone gap do.